# Closure of $l_1$ in $l_\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose we have a set $A$ which is the set of all sequences that satisfy $|x_n|\xrightarrow{} 0$. If we consider $l_1$ to be a subset of $l_\infty$. Show that the closure of $l_1$ in $l_\infty$ equals $A$.

I started by showing $l_1$ is closed since it is complete (even stronger condition is that it is compact in $l_\infty$ since it is closed in $l_\infty$). Then I can see why $l_1  \subseteq$ $l_\infty$ since this is a condition on converging (absolutely) series. This doesn't seem to make sense in the other direction... I think I'm seeing this wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $\ell_1$ is not closed in $\ell_\infty$.  It is complete in the $\ell_1$ norm, but not in the $\ell_\infty$ norm.  It is also not compact: no unbounded set can be compact.

To show that the closure of $\ell_1$ is $A$, you might proceed as follows.

a) show that $\ell_1 \subseteq A$.

b) show that any member of $A$ is the limit of a sequence of members of $\ell_1$.

c) show that $A$ is closed in $\ell_\infty$.

Comment: Is this all wrt $l_\infty$ norm?

Comment: Yes, it is all wrt $\ell_\infty$ norm.

Comment: So have I already shown the first part? $l_1 \subseteq A$ follows from the condition on absolutely converging series?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the condition".  It's the fact that the terms of a convergent series must go to $0$.

Comment: So I need to fix a sequence in $A$ (this sequence is bounded) ${x_n}$ and show that I can construct a sequence ${y_n}$ in $l_1$ s.t. $\max|x_n-y_n|<\epsilon$, and if each component of the sequence is to converge I have $|x_n^j-y_n^j|<\epsilon$

Comment: Sorry about that last comment... completely wrong - $A$ is the set of all sequences that converge

Comment: No, $A$ is the set of all sequences that converge to $0$.  Hint:
take $y_n = 0$ for sufficiently large $n$.